# Creating grid 16x16 into div container, using JavaScript and Flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with stretching my grids horizontally so they would fit perfectly mine container.
The task is to create grid 16/16 using flexbox and creating divs in js(then put it into container (sketch-screen) in html. The problem is i cant stretch as i want to. I tried to use flex:1 then 1 1 auto on divs in container but it did not want to work. I want it to fill all the space of the container so they will be squares not the rectangles. Plus then I would like to play with the size of grid.

```js
function makeGrids(size) {
  let screen = document.querySelector(".sketch-screen");
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    let column = document.createElement("div");
    column.classList.add("column");
    for (let j = 1; j <= size; j++) {
      let row = document.createElement("div");
      row.classList.add("row");
      row.style.border = "2px solid black";
      row.innerText = (i * size) + j;
      column.appendChild(row);
    }
    screen.appendChild(column);
  }
}

makeGrids(16);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #7d7d7d;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: auto;
  background-color: #555454;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.sketch-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #991101;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.sketch-screen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #bfbfbf;
}

.sketch-screen>div {
  height: auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sketch-container">
    <div class="sketch-screen">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <p>Design by 2023</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to make your `.column` vertical flexboxes:

```css
.sketch-screen>div {
  height: auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;

  /* make columns vertical flexboxes */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sketch-screen>div>* {
  /* make rows evenly distributed */
  flex: 1;
}
```

```js
function makeGrids(size) {
  let screen = document.querySelector(".sketch-screen");
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    let column = document.createElement("div");
    column.classList.add("column");
    for (let j = 1; j <= size; j++) {
      let row = document.createElement("div");
      row.classList.add("row");
      row.style.border = "2px solid black";
      row.innerText = (i * size) + j;
      column.appendChild(row);
    }
    screen.appendChild(column);
  }
}

makeGrids(16);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #7d7d7d;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: auto;
  background-color: #555454;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.sketch-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #991101;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.sketch-screen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #bfbfbf;
}

.sketch-screen>div {
  height: auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;

  /* make columns vertical flexboxes */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sketch-screen>div>* {
  /* make rows evenly distributed */
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sketch-container">
    <div class="sketch-screen">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <p>Design by 2023</p>
</footer>
```